# Building a properties file to the top level of a WAR file, Spring-MVC/Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven

I need to include a file into my war. Currently, in non Web applications the file in question is added to the top level directory, the class that uses it searches for this file at this level.

I need to use Maven, or somehow in the web app to include this file at the top level of the war file. My current directory structure is as follows:

```
Project
 |--Src/Main/Java
      |--Package
         |--X.class
 |--WebContent
      |-- META-INF
      |-- resources
      |-- WEB-INF
 |--POM.XML
 |--FileToInclude.Properties
```

The diagram above shows the X.class in my spring application, it uses the FileToInclude.properties file, and it must be at the top level. Any ideas?

This structure would work on a normal project, just not when its a web application and the certain files get built.

thanks

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415610/how-to-add-a-file-to-a-war-with-maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include that file in any directory that is part of the classpath.

If you need to include it **inside the war** you need to add in the `WEB-INF/classes` directory.

If you like to add it **externally** you can add it to any directory that is part of the classpath when your war is loaded by the application server. Generally is possible to specify to the application server which directories use as part of the classpath