# How do I add a file to the artifact (jar or war) created by maven?

Tags: maven

I have an antrun task (goal `run` on phase `prepare-package`) set up that creates a file and saves it in `/target/foo.bar`. How do I add that to the artifact that gets created by maven (depending on module, it could be a `jar` or a `war` file)?

I have tried it with resources, with the builder-helper plugin, and the jar plugin - no luck:

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>target</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>**/foo.bar</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

That doesn't seem to do anything.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>attach-artifacts</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <artifacts>
          <artifact>
            <file>${project.build.directory}/foo.bar</file>
            <type>bar</type>
          </artifact>
       </artifacts>
     </configuration>
   </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

According to debug output, this seems to install something extra in the repo, but doesn't add `foo.bar` to the artefact.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <includes>
       <include>../foo.bar</include>
    </includes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

No observable effect, either. :(

(I assume [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2415670/2018047) might work for the `war` file, but I'd prefer one way to do it for both artifact types, if possible - plus I really need this to work for the `jar`s, too...)

Is there a way to do what I want to do?
(I'd prefer not saving my file in src/main/resources first; I thought the packaging processes would pick files up from the build directory after they were placed there anyway, but I suppose I misunderstood something...)

Comment: Why are you using antrun task ? And not using Maven? Can you explain what you are doing by your antrun task? And why kind of file you are creating ?

Comment: Are you looking forward to using [maven-resource-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/)?

Comment: @nullpointer I thought that's what I use when I specify `resources`? And it doesn't work because it is only supposed to copy files to the `target` directory, and not to actually package them: "Copy resources for the main source code to the main output directory. Always uses the project.build.resources element to specify the resources to copy."

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm calling `mvn dependency:resolve` with it, to get a list of dependencies with version numbers instead of version ranges. If there is a better way to do that, I'd appreciate to hear about it. But even if, I'd still love to know if/how I can add random files to the artifacts maven generates for me. :)

Comment: And this output would you like to package into your resulting jar file correct?

Comment: This is defined in the parent pom file. Depending on the module, it can be a `jar` or a `war`. But yes, essentially.

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/khmarbaise/add-dependency-plugin/blob/master/pom.xml (Adding the output to the result jar file). Should also work for war file...

Comment: @khmarbaise It works, and even saves me running the antrun plugin, which is great. Thank you! What I don't understand is why it would work for the `war` for you, but not for me - I ended up putting the output into the exact same folder...

Answer (score 0):

I had my file saved to `project.build.directory`. Changing that to [`project.build.outputDirectory`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#classesDirectory) means the `jar` plugin is picking it up, without the need of any other plugins. Unfortunately, that doesn't sort the `war` issue out... :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and stored the resulting artifact in

```
target/${project.name}-${project.version}/foo.war
```

To be more precise, I created the war from a directory using the ant target

```
<war warfile="target/${project.name}-${project.version}/foo.war" basedir="somedir" />
```

Then it was correctly added to the surrounding ear.